# Unit testing with Spring Session JDBC

Tags: spring, unit-testing, session, jdbc, mockmvc

I developed a Java servlet that allows 2-Factor authentication.
First, I set up an endpoint (Web/authenticate/credentials) that accepts user credentials, checks if they exist in the database, in which case it returns the corresponding user challenge in the response, and set the user account ID in the session attribute.

Then, when the user receives the challenge, they provide a secret and send a request to a different endpoint (Web/authenticate/secret), which first checks if the requests is associated with any session, and then retrieves the user account ID from the session attribute to complete the authentication.

All this works well, when testing with Postman, but when I write some unit tests with MockMvc, a new session is always created as I send the secret to the second endpoint (Web/authenticate/secret), even when I explicitly set the SESSION cookie header.

Below is a snippet of the unit test that fails:

```
   MvcResult preAuthMvcResult = preAuthenticateUser(deviceAlias, userPin);//This calls the first endpoint

    // Get session cookie to send in next request header
    String sessionCookie = preAuthMvcResult.getResponse().getHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);


    JSONObject userCredentialsJson = new JSONObject();
    userCredentialsJson.put("secret", secret);

    // HTTP request
    HttpHeaders httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeader.add("x-api-key", apiKey);
    httpHeader.add(PRE_AUTH_HEADER, accountIdHash);
    httpHeader.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, sessionCookie);


    // Act
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
        .perform(post("/Web/authenticate/secret").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .headers(httpHeader).content(userCredentialsJson.toString()))
        .andReturn();

    // Assert
    int responseStatus = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();

// This fails the test because a new session is created, and the authication cannot proceed, as the server lost track of the authenticating user
    assertThat(responseStatus == HttpStatus.OK.value()).isTrue();
```